# Copying properties from a model back to an object -- copy explicitly or iterate over property collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm taking an object and writing its properties to a model, then showing the model in my view for editing. Afterwards, the user hits submit and the model is posted back to my controller. I would now like to take the model's properties and write them back to the object.

I am considering using reflection to do so, but I am a bit wary. Thought I would check if there is a more obvious answer.

Code:

```
//OrderDetailsModel
public OrderDetailsModel(Order order)
{
    CompletionDateTime = order.CompletionDateTime;
    CreateDateTime = order.CreateDateTime;
    UpdateDateTime = order.UpdateDateTime;
    BusinessArea = order.BusinessArea;
    Comment = order.Comment;
    CostCenter = order.CostCenter;
    CreateUsername = order.CreateUsername;
    Customer = order.Customer;
    IncidentNumber = order.IncidentNumber;
    OrderID = order.ID;
    OrderStatus = order.OrderStatus;
    ProjectName = order.ProjectName;
    ProjectNumber = order.ProjectNumber;
    ProjectSubcode = order.ProjectSubcode;
    UpdateUsername = order.UpdateUsername;
    Description = order.Description;
}

//OrdersController
public ActionResult SaveOrderDetails(OrderDetailsModel orderDetailsModel)
{
    Order order = WorkflowManager.GetOrderByID(orderDetailsModel.OrderID);

    foreach(PropertyInfo propertyInfo in orderDetailsModel.GetType().GetProperties)
    {
         //Write properties back.
    }

    return null;
}
```

Thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: why don't you just cache the original order than then set the properties with the data you have stored in your OrderDetailsModel? Better yet, why not just make the getters and setters in your OrderDetailsModel, use the getters and setters from the cached order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). It makes short work of this left hand<->right hand coding.

Here's an example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDetailsModel>();
OrderDetailsModel dto = Mapper.Map<Order, OrderDetailsModel >(order);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).  It maps properties with the same name without any custom coding.  You can add it to your project in Visual Studio using NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AutoMapper` pattern in order to accomplish this mapping.

Nota : You have project and libraries on github

Link : https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/)

After using both, Automapper and ValueInjecter, I would say that ValueInecter is definitely easier to use. It also doesn't need any setup done upfront before you want to map from one object to the other. As long as property names match, you can use the default functionality. It also supports flattening and unflattening.

Here is an example:

```
myObject.InjectFrom(anyOtherObject);
```

Don't forget to include the using statement after referencing the assembly:

```
using Omu.ValueInjecter;
```

Thanks.